# Multiple nested if conditions inside lambda

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

I have a column called zipcode in the pandas data frame. Some the rows contain NaN values, some contain correct string format like '160 00' and the rest contain the wrong format like '18000'. What I want is to skip NaN values (not to drop them) and convert wrong zipcodes into correct ones; for example: '18000' -> '180 00'.
Is it possible to do that by applying lambda? All I got is this so far:

```
df['zipcode']apply(lambda row: print(row[:3] + ' ' + row[3:]) if type(row) == str else row)
```

Sample of dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(['11100', '246 00', '356 50',
                            np.nan, '18000', '156 00', '163 00']), columns=['zipcode'])

  zipcode
0   11100
1  246 00
2  356 50
3     nan
4   18000
5  156 00
6  163 00
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are all the incorrectly formatted values present in the form `ddddd` and if i'm understanding correctly you want to change those values to form `ddd dd`? Also If possible can you please include a small sample of your column `zipcode`?

Comment: there is no magic bullet.  You are better off here to define a function that does all your error handling and returns the correct format; you can still use this with apply

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Yes, I want to change values to form ddd dd. 
```pd.DataFrame(np.array(['11100', '246 00', '356 50',np.nan,'18000', '156 00', '163 00']), columns=['zipcode'])```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us try [`.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html):

```
df['zipcode'] = df['zipcode'].str.replace(r'(\d{3})\s*(\d+)', r'\g<1> \g<2>')
```

---

```
  zipcode
0  111 00
1  246 00
2  356 50
3     nan
4  180 00
5  156 00
6  163 00
```